# UI Validation (Page layouts) with Dreamfactory

Tags: validation

Background:
We migrated a subset of data & configuration from one org to a new org. Migration involved:
1. Data 2. Meta data

We are at the phase of validating the data and UI. When I say UI validation we are validating the page layouts (comparing the page layouts in new org and old org). Currently we are doing it manually by having both the screens open in same window.

Is there any better way or tool to do the comparison of page layouts between two similar org's.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with raw text, you could use the metadata API to download the page layouts, then use a tool like diff or WinMerge to compare the contents of those text files. Since they should be identical, obvious differences should be easy to spot.

If you're not comfortable doing this yourself, and decent consultant should be able to easily check the files for you.